# How to return a List from Stream<List> method? Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, stream

I'm still quite new to Flutter and I use `flutter_bloc` for state management.
In bloc I'm listening to a repository method `Stream<List<UserAlert>> alerts()`.  In this method I listen both to `.onChildAdded` and `.onChildRemoved` events on a Firebase real time database node and update a local `List<UserAlert> alerts`, but I'm not succeeding in returning it once it updates so I get null value on bloc listener. `NoSuchMethodError: The method 'listen' was called on null.` I chose to manually manage it as I don't want to download the whole node at every change as it happen when listening to `.onValue`. I tried `return alerts as Stream<List<UserAlert>>` inside both firebase snapshot scopes but I get a type cast error.
I tried `Stream.value(alerts)` both inside each scope and as the very last thing in the method but still returns null.
How can I get `alerts` to be returned as a stream?
Thank you very much for your help.

Repository method:

```
Stream<List<UserAlert>> alerts() {
    print('alerts() called');
    Stream<List<UserAlert>> alertStream;

    List<UserAlert> alerts = [];
    // Option 2  return a list manually updated by two different events: More complicated but very efficient(bandwidth), lowest data consuming = Lowest Firebase bill.
    // returns one event per node record at app start and only new afterwards

    _alertSubscription = _databaseReference.onChildAdded.listen((Event event) {
      print(' observer .childAdded: added alert is : ${event.snapshot.value}');
      UserAlert userAlert = UserAlert.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot);
      alerts.add(userAlert);
//      alertStream = Stream.value(alerts); // alerts as Stream<List<UserAlert>>;
//      return alerts;

      print(
          'observer .childAdded: alerts are: $alerts and total alerts are ${alerts.length}');
    });

    // returns one event per node removed record
    _alertSubscription =
        _databaseReference.onChildRemoved.listen((Event event) {
      print(
          'observer .childRemoved: removed alert is : ${event.snapshot.value}');
      int index = alerts.indexWhere(
          (userAlert) => userAlert.id.startsWith(event.snapshot.value['Id']));

      print('index to remove is: $index');
      alerts.removeAt(index);

//      return alerts;
      print(
          'observer .childRemoved: alerts after removing are: $alerts and total alerts are ${alerts.length}');
//      return alerts;
    });
//    yield* alertStream;
    Stream.value(alerts);
  }
```

Bloc listener:

```
Stream<AlertState> _mapLoadAlertToState() async* {
    _alertSubscription?.cancel();
    _alertSubscription = _alertRepository
        .alerts()
        .listen((alerts) => add(AlertsUpdated(alerts)));
////        (List<UserAlert> alerts) {
////      print('_mapLoadAlertToState() userAlterts are: $alerts');
////      add(AlertsUpdated(alerts));
//    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed approach and now I get data from firebase as I was expecting with previous approach.
I decided to split Repository method into two different methods that transform the streams into `Stream<UserAlert` :

```
Stream<UserAlert> addedAlert() {
    print('addedAlert() called');
    handleData(Event event, EventSink<UserAlert> sink) =>
        sink.add(UserAlert.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot));

    final transformer = StreamTransformer<Event, UserAlert>.fromHandlers(
        handleData: handleData);

    return _databaseReference.onChildAdded.transform(transformer);
  }

  Stream<UserAlert> removedAlert() {
    print('removedAlert() called');
    handleData(Event event, EventSink<UserAlert> sink) =>
        sink.add(UserAlert.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot));

    final transformer = StreamTransformer<Event, UserAlert>.fromHandlers(
        handleData: handleData);

    return _databaseReference.onChildRemoved.transform(transformer);
  }
```

and handle the adding to and removing from `List<UserAlert>` inside the bloc method:

```
Stream<AlertState> _mapLoadAlertToState() async* {

    _addedAlertStreamSubcription =
        _alertRepository.addedAlert().listen((UserAlert alert) {
      print('received snapshot is:$alert.'); // prints null
      alerts.add(alert);
      print(
          'observer .childAdded: added alert is :$alert, we have ${alerts.length} active alerts, active alerts are: $alerts');
      add(AlertsUpdated(alerts));
    });

    _removedAlertStreamSubscription =
        _alertRepository.removedAlert().listen((UserAlert alert) {
      int index =
          alerts.indexWhere((userAlert) => userAlert.id.startsWith(alert.id));

      print('index to remove is: $index');
      alerts.removeAt(index);
      print(
          'observer .childRemoved: removed alert is :$alert, we have ${alerts.length} active alerts, active alerts are: $alerts');
      add(AlertsUpdated(alerts));
    });
  }
```

`AlertUpdated` will then trigger:

```
Stream<AlertState> _mapAlertsUpdatedToState(AlertsUpdated alert) async* {
    print(
        '_mapAlertsUpdatedToState() called, alerts are: ${alert.alerts} ');
    yield AlertLoaded(alert.alerts);
  }
```

`_mapAlertsUpdatedToState` prints are showing the correct List, but prints from `BlocListener`only show up once with one value in the list.

```
BlocListener<AlertBloc, AlertState>(
            listener: (BuildContext context, AlertState state) {
          if (state is AlertLoaded) {
            List<UserAlert> userAlerts = (state).alerts;
            print(
                'AlertListener userAlerts are: $userAlerts and total alerts are : ${userAlerts.length}');
          }
        }),
```

This is solved by making `AlertState` classes not extending Equatable as it would compare previous and new state and find them to be the same.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `yield` statement to return a Stream:

```dart
Stream<AlertState> _mapLoadAlertToState() async* {
    Stream<List<UserAlert>> _stream = _alertRepository.alerts();
    await for(List<UserAlert> alerts in _stream){
        yield AlertsUpdated(alerts);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but still  I still get an empty List as I'm not sending any List to the stream.  How to return the List in  `alerts()`?